# HTML - Columns ignore height

Tags: html, css

Right now I have this:

[image]

But I need something like this:

[image: Example]

HTML

```
    <div id="content">      
        <div class="block" style="height:600px;">

        </div>

        <div class="block" style="height:500px;">

        </div>

        <div class="block" style="height:500px;">

        </div>

        ...
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.block
{
    width:350px;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-bottom:80px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#content
{
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

I tried using columns but that didn't work well, it showed one column only even though the column count was higher than 1.

Comment: You're going to need flexbox to achieve this. Have a read through this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It called 'masonry layout'. Just google it and choose any realization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="third">
    <div class="grid grid1">
      <p>Grid 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid2">
      <p>Grid 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
   <div class="grid grid3">
      <p>Grid 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid4">
      <p>Grid 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    <div class="grid grid5">
      <p>Grid 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid6">
      <p>Grid 6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.third {
  display: inline-table;
  width: 30%;
}

.grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.grid1 {
  height: 200px;
}

.grid2 {
  height: 100px;
}

.grid3 {
  height: 100px;
}

.grid4 {
  height: 350px;
}

.grid5 {
  height: 200px;
}

.grid6 {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Now i have used lots of css classes here (grid1, grid2 ...), they normally dont have to be used, just set height: auto so it takes the height needed to show all content.

Working example can be found here:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/nuauntmo

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could put the vertically stacked blocks in separate containers. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="col"> 
        <div class="block" style="height:600px;">

        </div>

        <div class="block" style="height:500px;">

        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col">
        <div class="block" style="height:500px;">

        </div>

        <div class="block" style="height:500px;">

        </div>
    </div>
...
```

CSS:

```
.col {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:80px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.block {
    width:350px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom:80px;
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

The columns will wrap if there is not enough horizontal space though, so the container would have to have a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

try adding vertical-align property in css.

```
.block
{
    width:350px;
    background-color:grey;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-right:80px;
    margin-bottom:80px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;

}
```